# How to broadcast data from child window to parent modal popup in angular js

Tags: angularjs, postmessage, message-channel, broadcast-channel

I have to broadcast data from child window to parent modal popup controller from which new window originated

Comment: What are you using the show the modal? If you use the Angular UI Bootstrap [$uibModal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) you can pass a value back when you close the modal. If you truly want to use a broadcast-like event from a child to a parent then you'll need to use `$emit()`.

Comment: it not popup. my child is $window

Comment: So you're talking about communicating from a spawned window back to your Angular app? I don't think Angular supports this. You'll probably have to use something like [Broadcast Channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) (note: you'd need a polyfill for IE). Or, save yourself a lot of trouble and use a $uibModal instead of spawning a whole separate window.